# API Gateway is returning 403 Forbidden when being called from ECS

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have set up a API gateway in AWS, and when I am able to call it from an application running in my laptop without any issue. However, it's giving me 403 forbidden error when I deploy the app in ECS on Fargate and call the same URL of API gateway.

I've confirmed the API gateway has been deployed and I am passing the stage name correctly.

This is the error message I am getting with 403 HTTP status code.

```
header([Server:"Server", Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"24", Connection:"keep-alive", x-amzn-RequestId:"7e198xx8-5386-4xx7-axxf-a38cf78618b7", x-amzn-ErrorType:"ForbiddenException", x-amz-apigw-id:"cWxx5GSWXXcFuVg="])
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

And I am using this base endpoint URL

```
https://{api-id}.execute-api.(region-id}.amazonaws.com/{stage}
```

I have tried with various endpoint types (Regional, Edge, Private), but none of them were successful. I might have used wrong URL though.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong in this case?

Comment: Are you using API keys or something with your API Gateway? How is authentication being done?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. And it's not even being logged in the access logs for the gateway stage. Did you manage to find the root cause?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this issue?
I'm facing the same issue, I've reviewed the task policy and it has a Allow on all the API gateway resources, but I'm still getting a 403.

Comment: My solution for this was to disable the private DNS names to allow the access from VPC without custom domain name.